# Excel Formula: COUNTIF Function for range of values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to do a COUNTIF for a range of values.

First, I'm looking for records with a Year Home Built equal to or between 1955 and 1977. Then I'm looking for a count of those records where the last time a roof was updated equal to or between 0 and 5 years. Here is the formula I wrote, but I cannot get it to work:

=COUNTIF(IF(AND(Table1[Year Home Built]>=1955,Table1[Year Home Built]<=1977), IF(AND(YEAR(TODAY())-Table1[Year Roof Last Updated]>=0,YEAR(TODAY())-Table1[Year Roof Last Updated]<=5))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
=COUNTIFS(Table1[Year Home Built],">=1955",
    Table1[Year Home Built],"<=1977",
    Table1[Year Roof Last Updated],"<=" & YEAR(TODAY()),
    Table1[Year Roof Last Updated],">=" & (YEAR(TODAY())-5)
    )
```

Comment: @user2917409 If this does answer your question, you ought to accept it as the answer (click the checkmark to the left of my answer). See this for more info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.